# Logout при обновлении не сохраняется

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Когда пользователь зарегестрирован то isUserAuthed = true и появляется ник, фото профиля и logout при обновлении состояние сохраняется но когда пользователь выходит из аккаунта тоесть нажимает на logout он выходит но когда обноляет страницу, то пользователь остаеться авторизованным тоесть не выходит из системы.

Пробовал поменять user на isUserAuthed в условии, но это постоянно выводит в консоле logout

```
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (isUserAuthed) {
                console.log('login');
                const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = user
                const newuser = {
                    displayName,
                    email,
                    avatar: photoURL,
                    userId: uid
                }
                dispatch(setUserFromParams(newuser))
            } else {
                console.log("logout");
            }
        })
        dispatch(checkUserInSystem())
    }, [])
```

(это из-за того что useEffect в Layout сначало выводит user==null потом срабатывает signIn в userSlice?) signUpUser тоже почему то не работает

Layout.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { signIn, signOut, signUpUser } from '../../redux/slices/userSlice'
import { checkUserInSystem, setUserFromParams } from '../../redux/slices/userSlice';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../config';
import { Auth } from '../../Components/AuthModal/Auth';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
    const [isSigUp, setisSigUp] = useState(false)
    const [isUserAuthed, setIsUserAuthed] = useState(false)
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const logOut = () => {
        setIsUserAuthed(false)
        dispatch(signOut())
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {
                console.log('login');
                const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = user
                const newuser = {
                    displayName,
                    email,
                    avatar: photoURL,
                    userId: uid
                }
                dispatch(setUserFromParams(newuser))
            } else {
                console.log("logout");
            }
        })
        dispatch(checkUserInSystem())
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user, 'dididi');
        if (user.user == null) {
            setIsUserAuthed(false)
        } else {
            setIsUserAuthed(true)
        }
        console.log(isUserAuthed);
    }, [user, isUserAuthed])
    return (
        <>
            <Auth isClicked={isClicked} setIsClicked={setIsClicked} isSigUp={isSigUp} />
            <header>

                <div className='header'>

                    <div className='header__auth'>
                        {
                            isUserAuthed ?
                                <>
                                    <div className='header__username'>{user?.user?.displayName}</div>
                                    <img className='header__avatar' src={user?.user?.avatar} />
                                    <button className='header__logOut' onClick={logOut}>Log Out</button>
                                </> :
                                <>
                                    <button className='header__sign-up' onClick={(e) => {
                                        setIsClicked(true)
                                        setisSigUp(true)
                                    }}>Sign Up</button>
                                    <button className='header__sign-in' onClick={(e) => {
                                        setIsClicked(true)
                                        setisSigUp(false)
                                    }}>Sign In</button>
                                </>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <main>
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Auth.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Auth.scss'
import { auth, storage } from '../../config'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth'
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { signIn, signUpUser } from '../../redux/slices/userSlice'
import { redirect, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
export const Auth = ({ isClicked, setIsClicked, isSigUp }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const title = isSigUp ? 'Sign Up' : 'Sign In'
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    const [fileImg, setFileImg] = useState(null)
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState('')
    const dispath = useDispatch()

    const signUp = async (keyword) => {
        if (keyword == 'Sign Up') {
            console.log('gggg');
            const newUserInfo = { auth, email, password, moreInfo: { username, fileImg } }
            dispath(signUpUser(newUserInfo))
            setIsClicked(false)
        } else {
            const existUserInfo = { email, password }
            dispath(signIn(existUserInfo))
            setIsClicked(false)
            navigate('/feed')
        }
    }
    const showAvatar = (e) => {
        if (e.target.files[0] != null) {
            const file = e.target.files[0]
            setFileImg(file)
            console.log(file);
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            reader.onload = function () {
                setAvatar(reader.result)
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className={`modal ${isClicked ? 'active' : ''}`}>
            <div className={`modal__container ${isClicked ? 'active' : ''}`}>

                <div className='modal__close' onClick={() => {
                    setIsClicked(false)
                }}>X</div>

                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <form className='modal__form'>
                    {
                        isSigUp ? <>
                            <div className='modal__form-control'>
                                <input onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.target.value) }} type='text' className='modal__username' placeholder='Username' />
                                <small>Error</small>
                            </div>
                        </> : null
                    }
                    <div className='modal__form-control'>
                        <input onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} type='text' className='modal__email' placeholder='Email' />
                        <small>Error</small>
                    </div>
                    <div className='modal__form-control'>
                        <input onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} type='text' className='modal__password' placeholder='Password' />
                        <small>Error</small>
                    </div>
                    {
                        isSigUp ? <>
                            <img src={avatar}></img>
                            <div className='modal__file-wrapper'>
                                <input onChange={showAvatar} type='file' className='modal__file' id='modal__file' />
                                <label for='modal__file' className='modal__file-label'>
                                    Выберите файл
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </> : null
                    }
                    <button onClick={() => { signUp(title) }}>{title}</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

userSlice.js

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { auth } from "../../config";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUrlUploadedImg } from "../../utils/utils";
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    loading: false,
    error: null
}
export const signUpUser = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/signUp',
    async ({ auth, email, password, moreInfo }) => {
        try {
            console.log('sign');
            const urlImg = await getUrlUploadedImg(moreInfo.username, moreInfo.fileImg)
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, moreInfo)
            if (auth.currentUser != null) {
                console.log('up');
                await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
                    displayName: moreInfo.username,
                    photoURL: urlImg
                })
                const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = auth.currentUser
                const user = { displayName, email, avatar: photoURL, userId: uid }
                return user
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }

    }
)
export const signIn = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/SignIn',
    async ({ email, password }) => {
        const eemail = email
        try {
            const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, eemail, password)
            const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = auth.currentUser
            const user = {
                displayName,
                email,
                avatar: photoURL,
                userId: uid
            }
            console.log(user);
            return user
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
)
export const signOut = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/signOut',
    async () => {
        try {
            signOut(auth)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
)
export const checkUserInSystem = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/checkUserInSystem',
    async () => {
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
                try {
                    const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = user
                    const newuser = {
                        displayName,
                        email,
                        avatar: photoURL,
                        userId: uid
                    }
                    res(newuser)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            })
        })
    }
)
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUserFromParams: (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload
        }
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(signUpUser.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(signUpUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload
            state.loading = false
        })
        builder.addCase(signUpUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error.message
            state.loading = false
        })
        // !----------------------------------------------------
        builder.addCase(signIn.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(signIn.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload
            state.loading = false
        })
        builder.addCase(signIn.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error.message
            state.loading = false
        })

        // !----------------------------------------------------
        builder.addCase(signOut.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(signOut.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.user = null
            state.loading = false
        })
        builder.addCase(signOut.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error.message
            state.loading = false
        })
        // !----------------------------------------------------
        builder.addCase(checkUserInSystem.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = true
        })
        builder.addCase(checkUserInSystem.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.user = action.payload
            state.loading = false
        })
        builder.addCase(checkUserInSystem.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.error.message
            state.loading = false
        })
    }
})
export const { setUserFromParams } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

Comment: либо в layout.js замените `dispatch(signOut())` на `signOut(auth)` и уберите из слайсера, либо в слайсере настройте нормально функцию signOut - измените имя и импортируйте signOut из "firebase/auth"

Comment: @Arbery доходит. функция `signOut` выводит                                                                    
   `(dispatch, getState, extra) => {
        const requestId = options?.idGenerator ? options.idGenerator(arg) : nanoid();
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        let abortHandler;…`

Comment: @Arbery при замене не работает совсем

Comment: @Arbery logout работает только при обновлении пользователь остается авторизованным

Comment: в layout.js `signOut` из 'firebase/auth' подключили и убрали подключение его же из слайсера?

Comment: из слайсера не убирал и из  'firebase/auth'  не подключал

Comment: @Arbery спасибо решил